# Udp write datagram in QT timer signal

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, timer

I have a thread that send udp packets everytime  a timer expires.Timer interval is 20 seconds.I connected the timeout signal to send_data function.In the function i am doing some work and send packet with udp.In the funcion I also added a timer to know how much time the function consumes.

```
  QTimer timer;

  timer.setInterval(20);

  connect(timer,signal(timeout()),slot(send_data());

  send_data(){

     QElapsedTimer t;

     t.start();

     mysocket.writedatagram();//Do some work and send data via Udp

     cout<<t.elapsed()<<endl;
   }
```

I am printing the elapsed time and the time is sometimes 7ms i think it is normal, but sometimes it is 0 that comes me weird.I thought it is an issue related to udp packet sending and the function does not return in time?What can be the problem?

Comment: I assume you meant that you used a `QElapsedTimer` in `send_data`?  Also, can you please post the body of `send_data`?  We can't explain the results that you're getting without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that can be generated by t.elapsed do not have to go up in steps of 1, they will be extracted from a system clock by some means (it can vary). So if the clock it is using is going up in steps of 7 milliseconds, and your writeDatagram takes 4 milliseconds, sometimes you will get back zero because the clock did not tick, and sometimes you will get back 7 because a clock tick did occur during those 4 milliseconds.